# Unable to connect to ActiveMQ from .NET: No IConnectionFactory implementation

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, .net-4.5, apache-nms

I'm trying to connect to ActiveMQ from a .NET client. ActiveMQ server is up and running. I can access the admin console from my browser.

When I run the folowing code, I get an exception when trying to create the NMSCOnnectionFactory. I have no idea why this is happening nor how to fix it. I tried various ports but that does seem to be the issue. Any ideas?

```
"No IConnectionFactory implementation found for connection URI: amqp://localhost:61616/"

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  try
  {
    Uri connecturi = new Uri("amqp://localhost:61616");

    Console.WriteLine("About to connect to " + connecturi);

    IConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory(connecturi, "Bob", "protocol:" +   "amqp1.0");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception {0}.", e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for AMQP in the current releases of the NMS client libraries.  There is an experimental implementation in svn that you can try but you need to build it from source and then use it's own ConnectionFactory instance as the NMS API library does not have a mapping for it.  When the AMQP version is released you should be able to use code like this but you need to have both the NMS API lib and the NMS.AMQP lib referenced in your project.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim mentioned, there is no AMQP support in the current release.  However, the original code snippet will work (without having to link to specific provider implementation assemblies) by adding a configuration file to your project.  Name the file `nmsprovider-amqp.config`, with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <provider assembly="Apache.NMS.AMQP.dll" classFactory="Apache.NMS.AMQP.ConnectionFactory"/>
</configuration>
```

With this file in place, you only need to reference the `Apache.NMS.dll` assembly at compile time.  When the `NMSConnectionFactory` object is instantiated, it will try to load implementation providers for well-known protocols.  If an unknown protocol is specified in the connection URI (such as *amqp:*), it will then look for a filename following the format `nmsprovider-{protocol}.config`.  It will load that file to find the assembly and class factory name.  This allows the main NMS library to be extended at run-time with new provider implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me too. I solved it by making sure that the references "Apache.NMS" and "Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ" were included in the project. I used the NuGet Package manager to install them.